# R: Count rows with string matches in two columns

Tags: r, string, match

I have a file named "gamedata" with 30 columns (a mix of strings, numbers, and logicals), I need to count the number of rows where a string in column "home" matches "Seahawks" AND a partial string match in column "penalty" matches "*holding*".

All I need is a count of the total number of rows where (gamedata$home == "Seahawks" & gamedata$penalty == "*holding*").

I've tried several *wrong* solutions, which simply result in integer(0), when I can see that there are several valid instances.  Your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `sum(expression)`:

```
sum(gamedata$home == "Seahawks" & grepl("holding", gamedata$penalty))
```

Comment: I think the problem I am having stems from the wildcards I need for one of the strings.  The formula works until I add the string with the wildcard.

Comment: You can't just "add the string with the wildcard."  Update your question and tell us what the real problem is.

Comment: Just updated.  Thanks for your help and I hope that clarifies.

Comment: This is giving me an error message: "In grepl(gamedata$penalty, "\*holding\*") : argument 'pattern' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used"

Comment: @SoreFingerTips Sorry, switch around the parameters.  I had a typo in there.

Comment: `*holding*` is not a valid regular expression.  He probably needs simply `holding`.  Or `fixed=TRUE`

Comment: Thanks, Tim!  That worked, at last!  Matthew, the string with the penalties comes with a full sentence about the penalty, so the wildcard is needed, i.e. "Q4 PENALTY: Holding. #74 Offense ... "

Comment: @SoreFingerTips `grepl` returns true if the pattern matches the string.  This is not filename globing, it is a regular expression.  To match the word `Holding` alone (with no additional text) you would use the expression `^Holding$`.  The expression `Holding` matches the sentence which you posted.  Note that you might really want the expression `[Hh]olding`.